# How to build a document header?

Tags: header-footer

I have been working on print media and I would like to format my current word style to LaTeX. I am very new to this knowledge but wanting to learn for my profession. I am really looking forward for a header like this but been messing a lot myself with the code. I believe we can do it using table but my code is a mess. It would be great if someone helps me to fix this. I need this format above my page header. Sorry for not providing sample.

[image]

Comment: Please show some attempt you've made in achieving this and specify what you're struggling with. The point of this Q&A site is to solve specific problems, not to have other people do your work. The way it is right now, this question ought to be closed as _too localized_.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{confblue}{rgb}{.514,.792,1}
\definecolor{confgray}{gray}{.702}

\newcommand{\conferenceheader}{%
  \vspace*{-3cm}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \begin{minipage}{1.2\textwidth}
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=.33333\textwidth]{qFu74}}%
  \dimen8=\ht0 \fboxrule=0pt
  \large\sffamily
  \raisebox{-\fboxsep}{\usebox0}%\kern-.5\fboxsep
  \fcolorbox{black}{confblue}{%
  \parbox[b][\dimen8-2\fboxsep][t]{.33333\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
    ZooZooCampaign\\ Indra Park\\ Banglore}}%
  \fcolorbox{black}{confgray}{%
  \parbox[b][\dimen8-2\fboxsep][t]{.33333\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
    Ahmed Patel\\ CEO, IGRF systems\\[\baselineskip]
    \textcolor{blue}{\ttfamily Ahmed.patel@icrf.in}\\
    www.icrf.com}}\\[2ex]
  \fcolorbox{black}{confblue}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{>\/> Sponsors}}\\[1ex]
  IDEA Corporation\\
  Airtel Communication\\
  ICRF foundation\\
  Sree Bharathi Institutes, Banergatta Road
  \end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\conferenceheader

\end{document}
```

This is just an attempt to show some fine details of box setup.

[image]